# selenium-python click on coordinates: "unsupported operand type(s) for +"

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I work with automated tests on Robot Framework and I need to click on coordinates on a map.

I wrote this:

```
def click_at_coordinates(pos_x, pos_y):
    actions = ActionChains(get_driver())
    my_map = get_driver().find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='map']/div/div[4]/div")
    actions.move_to_element_with_offset(my_map, pos_x, pos_y).click().perform()
    get_driver().find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

And got this error message:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'`

Thank you!

*If needed:*

```
def get_driver():
    sl = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SeleniumLibrary")
    return sl.driver
```

Thank you for all your answers!

Comment: Can you share URL ?

Comment: I guess the error is for `actions.move_to_element_with_offset(my_map, pos_x, pos_y).click().perform()` code line. Can you put a breakpoint there and say what values are passed there? I want to know the contents of: `my_map`, `pos_x` and `pos_y`

Comment: What arguments are you passing in to `click_at_coordinates()` when it's called?

Comment: Are you up to date with the latest python selenium bindings?

Comment: Do you get any stacktrace in addition to the error message?

Comment: @cruisepandey , unfortunately, I cannot: you cannot access this page without an account, but you can see how it looks on https://geocontrib.dev.neogeo.fr/projet/236-projet-2021-06-04-135252514165/signalement/lister/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found by @Prophet:
The issue was in the robot file

```
${X1}    Set Variable    ${{ random.randint(1, 50) }}
${Y1}    Set Variable    ${{ random.randint(1, 50) }}

${X2}    Set Variable    ${{ random.randint(1, 50) }}
${Y2}    Set Variable    ${{ random.randint(1, 50) }}
```

Works perfectly fine with

```
${X1}    ${{ random.randint(1, 50) }}
${Y1}    ${{ random.randint(1, 50) }}

${X2}    ${{ random.randint(1, 50) }}
${Y2}    ${{ random.randint(1, 50) }}
```

Thank you for all the answers and help!

Answer (score 1):

Cast the arguments you're getting in the method to integers:

```
def click_at_coordinates(pos_x, pos_y):
    pos_x = int(pos_x)
    pos_y = int(pos_y)
    # the rest
```

, as you most probably are sending one as a string, the other as float from the test case (judging by the exception message).

You can also use type hints, Robot Framework will try to automatically cast the arguments you're calling with:

```
def click_at_coordinates(pos_x: int, pos_y:int ) -> None:
```

Comment: I don't think casting to integers will help, if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/6f25a6f9de78812c3dc3d4cc726071637a2187b9/py/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py#L253) for `move_to_element_with_offset()`, You'll see it already casts the arguments to int with `self.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_to(to_element, int(xoffset), int(yoffset))`

Comment: It seems to work when I replace pos_x and pos_y with figures

Comment: @C.Peck what can I say - given the code in the question, the only risky place was OP's arguments, all other methods are battle-proven code from a very popular library ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. Still, input sanitation is a good thing, and Benice later wrote the method works if args are replaced with numbers.